# jQuery click with changing .text value

Tags: jquery, click

I've got a slider on my main page that displays a picture and some text. After a few seconds, the picture changes and so does the text.

What I want to do is that when someone clicks on the text, it goes to the corresponding page.

For example: If the text is Chocolate, go to chocolate.php. Else if it's Vanilla, go to vanilla.php

However, with my current code, it always goes to chocolate.php no matter what the text says.

```
   walk:function(step) {
     $('#type').text(type_value[step]).on('click', function(){
          var selection = $('type').text(type_value[step]).value;
            if(selection = 'Chocolate') {
                window.location = 'selection/chocolate/';
                return false;
                } else if (selection = 'Vanilla') {
                window.location = 'selection/vanilla/';
                return false;
                }
            });
          }
```

I've also tried:

```
 walk:function(step) {
   $('#type').text(type_value[step]).click(function(){
      var selection = $('#type').text(type_value[step]).value;
        if(selection = 'Chocolate') {
            window.location = 'selection/chocolate/';
            return false;
        } else if (selection = 'Vanilla') {
            window.location = 'selection/vanilla/';
            return false;
            }
        });
```

Another thing I tried was without using var selection. Checking value directly in if statement instead.

Please let me know if you are confused by something, and I will be more than happy to clarify.

Thank you very much for your time, and for your help.

Comment: what's `$('#type').text(type_value[step])`?

Comment: @justjavac, this pulls text value from an array. That's what allows it to change from chocolate to vanilla.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When comparing you need to use `==` and not `=`.

Single `=` does an assignment ..

Besides that you need to use either `.val()` to get the value of the element if it is a form element (*or get the raw element first before using `value`*), or use `.text()` to get its text contents..

Comment: You sir, are awesome.
I changed to == and used .text() to store the variable, and it works. As you can see, I am a beginner in jQuery. Have a great week.

Answer (score 0):

- delete `value`
- change `=` to `==`

  walk:function(step) {
      $('#type').text(type_value[step]).click(function(){
          var selection = $(this).text(type_value[step]);   // delete value
          if(selection == 'Chocolate') {
              window.location = 'selection/chocolate/';
              return false;
          } else if (selection == 'Vanilla') {
              window.location = 'selection/vanilla/';
              return false;
          }
      });
  }

Answer (score 0):

Gaby's answer is spot on. Here is a refactored version of your code:

```
walk: function(step) {
    $('#type').text(type_value[step]).click(function(ev){
        ev.preventDefault();

        var selection = $(this).val().text().toLowerCase();
        window.location = 'selection/' + selection + '/';
    });
}
```

The only think that is not clear from your code is:

```
$('#type').text(type_value[step])
```

Seems suspect

Comment: that's a redundancy I corrected it in my answer above (at the end)

Comment: How would you do it if the selection was Chocolate Bar and you wanted to link to /chocolate-bar/? What you said works, I'm just curious! Thanks!

Comment: The refactored method above works by naming convention. It is up to you to make sure that your selection values match 1:1 with the names of your webpages. Alternatively you can write some logic to turn CamelCase to Camel-case if that is what you really want.

Answer (score 0):

Aside from the unfortunate typos with `=` vs `==` vs `===`, you may also need to delegate the `click` event from the bottom up since there's a few of em.

So instead of

```
$('#type')...on('click', function () {....
```

use this

```
$('#type').text(type_value[step]);
$('#slider').on('click', '#type', function () { 
    var selection = $(this).text();
......
```